# I'm getting '-U' invalid filename error while running sqlcmd

Tags: sqlcmd

This is the command I entered:

> sqlcmd -S 172.16.2.201 -d SampleDatabase -i "C:\temp\Service" –U
>   "user" -P "password"

And I'm getting the error:

> sqlcmd: '-U': Invalid filename.

The file location is correct but I don't know why the error is showing. Is the command wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the actual filename? This looks like a folder path to me since there's no extension

Comment: Is this exactly the command you tried to execute, literally copy-pasted here?

Comment: And is the output copy-pasted?

Comment: I just found out the solution to this error. I changed the sqlcmd a bit and got the output. The command goes like:                                                          sqlcmd -S 172.16.2.201 -d SampleDatabase –U "user" -P "password" -i "C:\temp\Service"